# AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'isnull'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, array-broadcasting, numpy-ufunc

I am trying to do EDA and running below code
data = data[~data.age.isnull()].copy()

Getting error as "AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'isnull'"
Please help me if anybody knows.
Thanks

I tried to convert the values but still did not get a perfect solution. What I am missing?

Comment: Likely, `data` is a Series/1D-array, and `data.age` return an element. What gives `type(data)`?